# Using subseq in clojure

Tags: clojure

Subseq:

```
    (subseq (apply sorted-set (range 10)) > 5 < 7) 
    ; (6)
```

This I understand -- but

```
    (subseq (apply sorted-set (range 10)) < 5 < 7)
```

also gives (6), even though (6 is not less than 5). Can someone explain what exactly happens when subseq is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
(subseq (apply sorted-set (range 10)) < 5 < 7)
```

`subseq` first creates a sequence `s` starting with `start-key`, which is `5`, so `s` becomes `(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`.

Then `subseq` uses `take-while` using `end-test` and `end-key` (`< 7`), but first checks if the first element of the new sequence `s` fullfills `start-test` with `start-key` (`< 5`). If it does not, it's not included in the resulting sequence.

`subseq` calls `take-while` with the sequence `(6, 7, 8, 9)`, and the result is `6`.

So `subseq` only checks one element for `< 5`, and this is `5` itself.

I hope that makes sense to you :-)

Also, you can always look at the source in the [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subseq#source).